# Rails comment association-model structure

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm building a small kind of blog website and some of it's models are post, user, comment, obviously.

**The question is:** Is the Comment model/table structured the right way? I'm asking this because it looks like **has many through** association but I only use **has many**.
I'm a little confused.

Is this structure correct?

I'll probably need to add comments association to the other models later.

ps. Right now the code below is working fine for me.

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.text :body
      t.references :user, index: true, foreign_key: true
      t.references :post, index: true, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
  end
end
```

-

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :posts
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :post
end
```

Comment: has many through is typically for many to many relationships. You're modeling looks fine. But you should prob ask this at codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: thanks for advice. I'll make a  posting there

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about working code.  The OP is going to post it on CR.

Comment: @WayneConrad this is not off-topic since he is asking about how has_many though relationships work. StackOverflow is not just for debugging broken code.

Comment: @WayneConrad I've reposted this question 20mins ago on CR. I think I'm gonna delete it from there since I got the answer in this thread. I think It shouldn't be closed too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes the relation is defined correctly.

`has_many though` is used when the relation is goes through another model:

```
class Band
  has_many :albums
  has_many :songs, through: :albums
end

class Album
  belongs_to: :band
  has_many :songs
end

class Song
  belongs_to :album
  has_one :band, though: :album
end
```

The key here is the `songs` table does not have a `artist_id` column rather you need to join the albums table when querying for `song.band` or `band.song`.

```
irb(main):009:0> Song.find_by(name: 'Sympathy for the Devil').band
  Song Load (0.3ms)  SELECT  "songs".* FROM "songs" WHERE "songs"."name" = ? LIMIT 1  [["name", "Sympathy for the Devil"]]
  Band Load (0.1ms)  SELECT  "bands".* FROM "bands" INNER JOIN "albums" ON "bands"."id" = "albums"."band_id" WHERE "albums"."id" = ? LIMIT 1  [["id", 4]]
=> #<Band id: 4, name: "Rolling Stones", created_at: "2015-06-23 20:08:14", updated_at: "2015-06-23 20:08:14">
irb(main):010:0>
```